# Share Folder on AIX

Tags: aix, shared-directory

I tried 'share folder aix' and I got few subjects that don't match mith my purpose.

So, I want to create a shared folder, between several servers (all of them on AIX 7.1.0.0), the principle is that once a server create a file on that folder, all servers can see'em.

It could be great if I don't have to install something, can you please help me, I don't know from what to start.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-setup-nfs-v3-aix-5x6x) you can find IBM manual how to start NFS and share folder with.

1. Install `box.net.nfs*` packages
2. With `smitty mknfsexp` configure the directory to be shared
3. Start NFS daemon
4. Check on client if you see the share `showmount -e <server name>`
5. `smitty mknfsmnt` to mount the filesystem